# Transfer Values of a Column from One Table to Another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my table's 'Overall' column values to be added to the next available column in a second table with the click of a button, I have seen other questions similar to this in SQL and My SQL but I am unsure on how to do this in jQuery. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('.item'); 
    var checkedItems = row.find(":checked")
    if (checkedItems.length == 5) {
      row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
    }
  })

  function getOverall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
  }


});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 95%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align=center>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Skating</th>
      <th>Shooting</th>
      <th>Passing</th>
      <th>Puck Control</th>
      <th>Team Play</th>
      <th>Overall</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" data-id="1">
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall">
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="2">
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall">
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

If i fully understend what you asked, is how to print the overall on the second table overall column. 
What i suggest you to do is to print the **total** variable to both *td* with the overall class.

when you do:

    `if (checkedItems.length == 5) {
          row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
    }`

the find function, as described in [jquery documentation to find function](https://api.jquery.com/find/),

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .find() method allows us to search through the **descendants** of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

so all you need to do is search for *td.overall* that inside the document with $(selector);

check this out:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('.item'); 
    var checkedItems = row.find(":checked")
    if (checkedItems.length == 5) {
      $("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
    }
  })

  function getOverall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
  }


});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 95%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align=center>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Skating</th>
      <th>Shooting</th>
      <th>Passing</th>
      <th>Puck Control</th>
      <th>Team Play</th>
      <th>Overall</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" data-id="1">
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall">
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="2">
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall">
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, what I meant was to add a second table and get the Overall  column's values to print out there when you clicked a button.

Comment: You want to create a third overall column with the sum of both ?

Comment: No, I want to create a 2nd and completely different HTML table and have the code add the values of the 'Overall' row into the first available column in the 2nd HTML table.

Comment: sorry man, i cant get exactly what you want to do.

after the user complete to check all of the radio buttons and there is an overall score, you want to create a new table, and copy the values from the overall to the where?

Comment: To the first column in the new table.

Comment: I've found questions where they managed to do it with rows, so I think its possible to modify the code so that it copies cells with a certain id into another table. Here is the link to the fiddle that can copy rows into the next table if your interested: http://jsfiddle.net/wGGDb/.